# Applescript will not run in automator

Tags: applescript, automator

This is the code I have, besides this, there's nothing else in the automator program currently.

```
on run {input, parameters}

delay 0.5

activate application "Firefox"

set x to 1
set counter to 0

repeat while (counter < x)
    tell application "System Events" to key code 126
    set counter to counter + 1
end repeat

set x to x + 1

return input
end run
```

The error I get when I run this is:

**The action “Execute AppleScript” encountered an error.**
Check the actionʼs properties and try running the workflow again.

Answer (score 0):

Either get rid of the (unused/unnecessary) parameters and return line, or get rid of the run block altogether. You don't need any of that for what you are doing. Whether or not you will need 'input' and other parameters later is another question. But this is just typing up arrows in FireFox.

```
activate application "Firefox"

set x to 1
set counter to 0

repeat while (counter < x)
   tell application "System Events" to key code 126
   set counter to counter + 1
end repeat

set x to x + 1
```

Comment: I tried this before, but I get these errors: The action "Execute Applescript" was not supplied with required data. And. No computers.